# pythonic way to find common key value pair among list of dict

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

I have a list of dictionaries.

```
alljson = [{'EchoTime': 0,
  'FlipAngle': 90,
  'MRAcquisitionType': '2D',
  'MagneticFieldStrength': 3,
  'Manufacturer': 'SIEMENS',
  'ManufacturerModelName': 'TrioTim',
  'RepetitionTime': 2,
  'ScanOptions': 'FS',
  'ScanningSequence': 'AP',
  'SequenceVariant': 'SK',
  'TaskName': 'Tom'},
 {'EchoTime': 0,
  'FlipAngle': 90,
  'MRAcquisitionType': '2D',
  'MagneticFieldStrength': 3,
  'Manufacturer': 'SIEMENS',
  'ManufacturerModelName': 'TrioTim',
  'RepetitionTime': 2,
  'ScanOptions': 'FS',
  'ScanningSequence': 'EP',
  'SequenceVariant': 'SK',
  'TaskName': 'fb'},
 {'EchoTime': 0,
  'FlipAngle': 90,
  'MRAcquisitionType': '2D',
  'MagneticFieldStrength': 3,
  'Manufacturer': 'SIEMENS',
  'ManufacturerModelName': 'TrioTim',
  'RepetitionTime': 2,
  'ScanOptions': 'FS',
  'ScanningSequence': 'EP',
  'SequenceVariant': 'HK', 
  'TaskName': 'Tom-loc'}]
```

Now i intend to find all common key value pairs from the list of dict. 
what would be the most pythonic way  to do it.

Note: key and value both should match, and k:v pair should exist in all dict

I tried all solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900308/find-all-key-elements-by-the-same-value-in-dicts) but given values are non hashable, none of the solution fully works.

any suggestions?

Comment: All three dicts in your list are the same. What exactly do you want to return?

Comment: Your values do look pretty hashable from where I am standing.

Comment: @lordingtar i have tried explaining your question in edit. Also dict now are not same

Answer (score 3):

Convert each dictionary's list of items into a set, find the set intersection, and optionally convert the result back to a dictionary:

```
dict(set.intersection(*[set(d.items()) for d in alljson]))
#{'MRAcquisitionType': '2D', 'FlipAngle': 90, 'RepetitionTime': 2,
# 'ScanOptions': 'FS', 'ManufacturerModelName': 'TrioTim', 
# 'Manufacturer': 'SIEMENS', 'SequenceVariant': 'SK', 'EchoTime': 0, 
# 'MagneticFieldStrength': 3, 'ScanningSequence': 'EP'}
```

Comment: I dont think this is exactly correct. EchoTime occurs 3 times but this returns 0 in my tests.

Comment: @putonspectacles Check again. It is returned in my case.

Comment: ahh, I misread the question, he asked for just the unique occurrences. I really like this, showing off the python expansion `*`

Comment: @DYZ it gves me error saying `'dict' object is not callable`

Comment: @learnningprogramming You must have redefined `dict` somewhere in your program. Make sure you do not have anything like `dict=...`, then restart your interpreter.

Comment: @DYZ yes you were correct. I deleted dict obj created before. But now the issue is it gives following error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: When I create the list of dictionaries using the code from your question and then execute the code from my answer, I get the right result. I suggest you do the same. The error that you see must be elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "common" pairs, but assuming you mean 'pairs present in every dictionary', you can convert each dictionary to lists of tuples and then find the intersection of all of the lists:

```
list_of_lists = [x.items() for x in alljson]
common_pairs = set(list_of_lists[0]).intersection(*list_of_lists)
print(common_pairs)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import operator as op
>>> reduce(op.iand, map(set, [d.items() for d in alljson]))
```

Comment: lovely, here is the docs on operators:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Comment: FYR, function `reduce` has been deprecated in Python 3.

Comment: @DYZ I wouldn't say deprecated, but yes it was moved off ``__builtins`` into the ``functools`` module so it requires an ``import``.  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Answer (score 0):

```
 reduce(lambda x, y: dict(set(x.items()).intersection(set(y.items()))), alljson)
```

Comment: FYR, function reduce has been deprecated in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
{k : v for x in alljson for (k, v) in x.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is longer but to me it's intuitive:

```
count = {}
final = []

for dictionary in alljson:
  for key in dictionary:
    if key in count:
      count[key] += 1
    else:
      count[key] = 1

for key in count:
  if count[key] == len(alljson):
    final.append(key)

print final
```

Loop through alljson and count how many times each key shows up. Then return only the keys that show up in every dictionary.