# comparing the values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries dic_1 and dic_2.

```
dic_1={"HI":"HELLO" , "NAME":"XYZ"}
dic_2={"HI" : "HELLO" , "NAME" : "XYZ" , "AGE" : "YY"}
```

I want to compare the key ,value pairs of these two dictionaries.If the values are same then output should print "YES" else "NO". It should check the values of the common keys in both dictionaries.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Related: [pythonic way to find common key value pair among list of dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42820548/1324033)

Comment: Please  elaborate on what you exactly need.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I figured out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want a single output for the entire test, you could make use of the [`all()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
dic_1={"HI":"HELLO" , "NAME":"XZ"}
dic_2={"HI" : "HELLO" , "NAME" : "XYZ" , "AGE" : "YY"}
if all(dic_1[k] == dic_2[k] for k in dic_1 if k in dic_2):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic_1={"HI":"HELLO" , "NAME":"XZ"}
dic_2={"HI" : "HELLO" , "NAME" : "XYZ" , "AGE" : "YY"}
for k in dic_1:
    if k in dic_2:
       if dic_1[k] == dic_2[k]:
            print "Key and value bot matches "
       else:
            print "NO"
```

Comment: Congratulations on finding a solution and posting it here. The only drawback is that you'll get feedback for every item in `dic_1` instead of a summary.